# Get the value of a custom user field

Tags: users, 8

I have a custom form that needs to display a default value from a custom user field. The field was created under /admin/config/people/accounts/fields and its machine name is field_r_period_length_sec.

```
//get user
$userCurrent = \Drupal::currentUser();
$uid = $userCurrent->id();
$r_period = $userCurrent->field_r_period_length_sec;
```

However, the value doesn't show and I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined property: Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy::$field_r_period_length_sec

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Berdir's answer gave me a search term that got me this:

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
```

After a bit of trial and error, this is the code that works, in case anyone else needs:

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$r_period = $user->field_r_period_length_sec->value;
```

For multiple values, use

```
$r_period = $user->get('field_r_period_length_sec')->getValue();
```

Comment: For anyone wanting remove the warning from PHPStorm in `$r_period = $user->field_r_period_length_sec->value;` add this comment `/** @var $user \Drupal\user\Entity\User */` above `$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());`

Answer (score 3):

The current user object is not a user entity. You need to load the user with that ID to access any field except the information specified by `AccountInterface`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know since when these answers doesn't work anymore, but with Drupal 8.5 the above solution return null all the time.

After investigation the solution to access custom field from a user profile is:

```
$activeProfile = \Drupal::getContainer()
  ->get('entity_type.manager')
  ->getStorage('profile')
  ->loadByUser(User::load([uid]), '[profile_machine_name]');
```

Then you can do

```
$activeProfile->field_xxx->value
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get specific field from the user profile. But im wondering how can you set/update a profile field name? TIA

Comment: $profile->set('field_name', value)

Answer (score 1):

`Entity::load()` is based off of `\Drupal::entityManager();` which is [deprecated](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8.4.x).

A better way to do this is by using entityTypeManager().

```
$user = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load($current_user->id());
$r_period = $user->field_r_period_length_sec->value;
```