# Get the value of a custom entity field

Tags: entities, 10

How can I get the value of a custom field added to user profiles?

I read and tested everything I found on Google, including the following code.

```php
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$custom_field_value = $user->field_custom_field->value;
// $custom_field_value = $user->get('field_custom_field')->value;
```

It does not work, though.

How can I get the value of a custom field in user profiles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the value of a custom user field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195238/get-the-value-of-a-custom-user-field)

Comment: Your field is named custom_field or field_custom_field. You can’t refer to the same field by two names.

Comment: hi cilefen, your thread and the code provided doenst work. i have already test it.  i fixed my message and copy/paste error for the field name, sorry for the mistake

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? The Question does not say. You should add this information to the Question. There is nothing here to distinguish your question from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195238/get-the-value-of-a-custom-user-field except "doesn't work", but that isn't anything to go on.

Comment: You've added the field to the user profile, but you are looking for it in the user entity. It's possible you mean the same thing, but since there is a popular module Profile it's not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you've added a new field through `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` and wish to retrieve its value, try the below code:

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

// Get the current user.
$current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();

// Load the user entity.
$user = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load($current_user->id());

// Check if the user entity exists and has the specified field.
if ($user && $user->hasField('field_custom_field')) {
  // Access the value of the 'field_custom_field' field.
  $custom_field_value = $user->get('field_custom_field')->value;
  
  // Now $custom_field_value contains the value of the field.
  // You can use it as needed.

}
else {
  // The user entity or the specified field doesn't exist.
}
```

Comment: This code is not materially different from the OP’s example.

Comment: Hey @cilefen, I'm not sure what's ( OP’s example). In this code I used `getStorage`.

Comment: They haven’t explained what “doesn’t work” means. Possibly they haven’t loaded a user object, which is what you are insinuating.

Comment: Correct. Based on the assumption that a new field was added via `admin/config/people/accounts/fields`, the goal is to retrieve the value of this field